# Automorphism group of a variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, automorphism-groups

Suppose $X$ is a (quasi-projective) variety over a field $k$, and let $\mathbb{P}^n(k)$ be the ambient projective space.

> When can one decide that the automorphism group of $X$ is induced by a subgroup of the automorphism group $\mathbf{P G L}_{n + 1}(k)$ of $\mathbb{P}^n(k)$ ?

When $X$ itself is a sub-projective space over $k$, this is of course well known, but when $X$ is e.g. an affine subspace over $k$, this is in general not true (due to the existence of non-linear automorphisms).

> Is it true when $X$ is projective ?

Answer (score 10):

I guess this should be true if and only if $f : X \to X$ fixes a polarization, i.e. there is an ample $A$ such that $f^\ast A \sim A$.

If there is such an $A$, then take the embedding of $X$ into $\mathbb P^n$ by a very ample $mA$.  The automorphism of $X$ is then induced by the linear map $f^\ast : \mathbb PH^0(X,mA) \to \mathbb PH^0(X,mA)$.  Conversely, if a map comes from a linear map on projective space, then the polarization given by restricting the hyperplane is fixed.

Typically automorphisms won't fix any polarization, so don't come from $\mathbb P^n$.  If you actually want to check it for a specific map, the first thing to do work out the induced map on $H^2(X;\mathbb R)$.  If there is an invariant ample divisor, its first chern class will be invariant under the pullback.  So you may be able to show that this doesn't happen.  If there is a fixed class, you need to know (a) whether it is represented by an ample divisor, which may or may not be easy to check depending on what $X$ is and (b) whether the divisor is linearly equivalent (rather than just numerically equivalent) to its pullback, which requires a bit more scrutiny.

As Francesco points out, $K_X$ always pulls back to itself under an automorphism, so if it's either ample or antiample you have what you want.

Comment: Nice. And this shows exactly what is happening with the elliptic curve example, since for an ample divisor $A$ and a translation $T$ by $P_0$, one has $T^*A\sim A$ if and only if $P_0$ is killed by $\deg(A)$, which is $\ge1$ by the ampleness assumption.

Answer (score 5):

> Is it true when X is projective ?

Let $X\subset\mathbb P^2$ be an elliptic curve and let $T:X\to X$ be a translation map $T(P)=P+P_0$ by a non-torsion point $P_0$. Then $T$ is an automorphism, but it is not induced by an element of $\text{PGL}_3$. Maybe a better question is whether, given a projective variety and an automorphism, does there exist *some* projective embedding for which the automorphism is induced by an element of $\text{PGL}$.

Comment: That's not true either -- such an automorphism always fixes a polarization on X, given by the restriction of the hyperplane from P^n.  But general automorphisms don't fix any polarization; infinite order automorphisms of surfaces are a typical counterexample.  The action of an infinite order element of $SL_2(\mathbb Z)$ on $E \times E$ ($E$ an elliptic curve) should give an example.  To see that it doesn't fix a polarization, you can just look at the induced map on $H^2$.

Comment: @Joe: why is $T$ not induced by an element of $\mathbf{PGL}_3(k)$ ?

Comment: @THC Take $P_0$ to be generic and look at the addition formula. It's pretty clearly non-linear in the coordinates of $P$. (Not a proof, but that's the intuition.)

Comment: @Mark I wasn't suggesting that the latter question had an affirmative answer. I was merely pointing out to the OP a more natural question, which I suspected also had a negative answer.

Comment: Ah, sorry!  I think you are right that non-torsion translations on $E$ are the basic example one should keep in mind, for either form of the question.  (In that case I don't think it can be linear wrt to any projective embedding.)

Comment: @Joe: thanks ! "Translation" is of course defined using the group law of the elliptic curve ...

Answer (score 4):

What you want is true if $X$ is embedded using some integer power of $K_X$, in particular it is true for canonically and anti-canonically embedded varieties.

In fact, any automorphism preserves the canonical class, so it necessarily preserves the hyperplane class under our assumption.

For the same reason, the answer is *yes* for varieties $X$ such that $\textrm{Pic}(X)= \mathbb{Z}$. In fact, if $L$ is the ample generator of the Picard group of $X$, then the hyperplane class is $H=kL$ for $k \geq 1$ and this must be preserved by all automorphisms, because they clearly preserve $H$.

Then the Noether-Lefschetz theorem implies that what you want is true for the very general *smooth* surface $X \subset \mathbb{P}^3$, and for all *smooth* hypersurfaces  $X \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ with $n \geq 4$.

For general embeddings $X \hookrightarrow \mathbb{P}^n$ the answer is negative, as shown by the proposed counterexamples.

Comment: Similarly, if $\operatorname{Pic}(X) \cong \mathbf Z$ and the embedding is linearly normal.

Comment: Yes, in fact I just added this, thanks.